# Typetexp.Error in OCaml Toplevel (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ocaml, ocaml-toplevel

I have recently installed Eclipse with OCaml plug-in and cygwin (for binaries Eclipse asked for) on Windows 10. I really need to work with OCaml Toplevel, but all it does is

```
OCaml version 4.02.3
Fatal error: exception Typetexp.Error(_, _, _)
Process ended with exit value 2
```

I have no slightest idea, how to fix it, and i have to work with it in few days...

Comment: Nevermind, friend of mine told me that it's effect of invalid lib path. Problem solved.